# Should we penalise people who vote to close questions that should not be closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The power to close questions is prone to abuse in this SE, seems people with the power to close questions have more power than everyone else, ie those that want to answer questions, those that would learn something from the question, those that asked the question but because 5 people can vote to close the question, it will be closed, no good reason. Some genuine on topic, not broad questions are closed because 5 people have something against the OP, they have voted and that is that. This is spoiling the good out of this otherwise great community.

Should we penalise people who vote to close questions that should not be closed?

Comment: You make a lot of assertions here. 1) That people who vote to close don't want to *also* answer questions. 2) That there isnt a good reason to close the questions 3) That questions being closed are done so for the reason of the author rather than the content. 4) That this is spoiling the community. And beyond that how do you suppose we would determine *when* to penalise. It sounds to me like you should possibly be looking at the questions themselves rather than the people closing them.

Comment: If we can all determine that there is no particular reason as to why a question has been closed and we we candetermine a pattern that a certain group of people will conspire to close a particular OP's question regardless of how relevent then should we take action or not.  Im merely stating that this close vote is prone to abuse thats all

Comment: Do you want to link to some specific question(s) you think *shouldn't* have been closed?

Comment: While 5 people can close a question, people can also vote to re-open a question.  If a question is closed, and not reopened, it is because of the question.

Comment: here is one https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50778/what-is-the-cost-of-renting-a-hangar-for-private-jet-storage

Comment: here is another https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50651/what-are-the-regulations-regarding-building-a-very-large-private-runway?noredirect=1#comment131998_50651

Comment: No, that is an objectively bad question.  The cost of storage of these jets will vary wildly across the country, and depending on the features of the hanger. Storage of those two jets is unlikely to be of broad interest to most users of this site.  The price of storage space is only tangentially related to aviation.

Comment: Its an aviation related question and where else would one curious about these quesion ask?  If I was not interested about the physics of fan or propeller design, should I vote to close such questions?  Other than security and location,  Im confident, there is not much that differs interms of features

Comment: Can we let those users decide as to whether or not they'd would be interested in th storage of those two jets.  Are you saying storing jets is not important in aviation? What about dirt and debri damaging the engines, how about sabotage to engines, will that not cause accidents. Is that not aviation safetey.  Cost is very much part of aviation for commercial aviation most importantly and should be for the military

Comment: I am a user.  And I did decide.  I think its not a good question, and 4 other people agree with me.  When you say, let the users decide, you are trying to silence my opinion.

Comment: How about the other thousands that use the site and why do votes to close questions come from the usual culprits? Should your voice and opinion then decide other users should not see this question cause once its closed, the likelihood that others will see it to reopen it is slim

Comment: If someone suggests that it be reopened it will go into the queue for people to look at it and decide if they want to vote to reopen. If you make it clear in the question and comments that you have made an effort to improve the question and address comments, that goes a long way. And you're welcome to stop by chat to discuss. It's not uncommon for people to ask for help in reopening questions there.

Comment: securitydude, I hope you realize that you are just begging for people to vote to close this question.  8^o

Answer (score 8):

No. We should not.

Giving users of a stack exchange site the ability to vote to close questions which are badly worded, off topic, or otherwise unwanted brings a lot of benefit to the wider community.

The fact that 5 such votes are required before a question is put on hold provides adequate checks and balances that it is not at the whim of a single user. The only time this changes is any user with a very high rep in the tag(s) you use is considered to have the authority to put a question on hold without other user's vote. Anyone using this facility incorrectly should be flagged for moderator attention.

Answer (score 5):

No, we should not do that, we will not do that, and we cannot do that.

I can feel your pain because you *think* that people don't like your questions, [which is not true](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33872/65). Although it is true you do ask some questions which did not get popular, but the community does *help* you. There are people who edit your questions to make those better or talk to you in comments.

You did not go to chat to discuss your questions. That is **very** helpful for others to understand the motive behind your questions.

Rest assured, and trust me that we (many users and mods) are trying our best to look at the question, not the person asking the question.

Regarding your assertion that [your question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50778/65) is aviation related, be a judge on this:

> What is the airfare when traveling from New York to London?

This is aviation related, isn't it? It is simple, isn't it? Yet it **will** be closed immediately as being too broad, because it is. There are many factors which will change the answer. That is the exact problem with your hangar fee question.

Comment: Your example would also fall foul of being `The "passenger aspects" of commercial air travel` as specified here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Jamiec Yes. I was giving an example of an apparently aviation related question which is not in fact aviation related.

Comment: Yes indeed. Its just id hope that got closed as off topic, not too broad :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Not only not, but absolutely not

> Should we penalise people who vote to close questions that should not be closed?

To make this suggestion is to completely misunderstand how this particular system is supposed to work.  Community moderation is a desired feature, because our few diamond mods can't be babysitting a given SE site all of the time.  These are volunteers, not paid Stack employees.  Instituting a punishment feature, a revenge feature, as you have suggested would disincentivize community moderation activity.  That's a poor recommendation.

#### There are checks and balances in the system.

You have enough rep to understand how privileges are unlocked, and how various community mod tools work (or are supposed to work).  The various levels of check are:

1. It takes 5 votes to close, unless a diamond mod shuts a Q or A down due to a flag or serious violations of SE policy.
2. Closed questions can be reopened. It takes effort, but a successful reopen effort can take place.  I've seen this done on six different SE's that I participate in. Recently, for example, [a nice, informed user at another SE highlighted an incorrect closure, and the question got reopened by *using the tools we already have*.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124040/how-would-halia-react-if-the-pcs-clear-out-the-redbrand-hideout-but-three-ruffia/124068#comment306318_124040)
3. A diamond mod can reopen a question if it fits the site's format well enough.

Discouraging participation in community moderation actions is antithetical to how the community moderation function is designed.  Try to make the system work.

#### There are ample ways to communicate with people who VTC but who might have erred.  (Hey, it happens, we are all human!)

- Chat
- Meta
- Comments
- Edits

All of these features open the door for an OK question to go from closed to open.

Pro Tip in interpersonal skills: *Talk to people with whom you disagree,* rather than proposing a rule to punish people who you disagree with.  I think you'll be pleasantly surprised at the outcomes.

#### Bottom Line

You have some self learning that needs to occur.

1. Learn how this SE system is supposed to work.
2. Review the Help and Q&A regarding the community mod features.
3. Review all of the various privileges we have at our level of rep